# What are the built-in git log formats?

Tags: git

In reading about [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), I have discovered it is possible to choose from an array of built-in formats (e.g. `--pretty=reference`) or create your own.  Custom "PRETTY FORMATS" are quite capable, with many placeholders to choose from and the option to add colors too.

However, I have no need to create a format from scratch.  I would rather tweak the presets that ship with git.  Are the format strings for these presets available so I can pass them to

```
git log --pretty=format:<format-string>
```

and change them as desired?

Comment: Some of the "magic" (built in) formats can be reconstructed from directives, but some cannot. See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72752400/1256452). I think at some point the formatting language should be beefed-up and all formats should be converted to their directive equivalents, but I have no idea when or if this will ever actually happen. (It's not very high on *my* priority list...  what's there works, and this would be a lot of work to implement, for no immediate gain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see some of the preset format-string used by Git in [`builtin/shortlog.c#shortlog_add_commit()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39c15e485575089eb77c769f6da02f98a55905e0/builtin/shortlog.c#L211-L245=), for instance.

Example:

```c
if (log->groups & SHORTLOG_GROUP_AUTHOR) {
        strbuf_reset(&ident);
        format_commit_message(commit,
                      log->email ? "%aN <%aE>" : "%aN",
                      &ident, &ctx);
        if (!HAS_MULTI_BITS(log->groups) ||
            strset_add(&dups, ident.buf))
            insert_one_record(log, ident.buf, oneline_str);
    }
    if (log->groups & SHORTLOG_GROUP_COMMITTER) {
        strbuf_reset(&ident);
        format_commit_message(commit,
                      log->email ? "%cN <%cE>" : "%cN",
                      &ident, &ctx);
```

But that illustrates that those preset are not available in a neat list somewhere, rather used directly in the Git source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can consult all available preset options at
https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Note that you can build your own using `format:<format-string>`, all available options for the format string being also described in the man page above.

Comment: Those are the presets and custom formatting I refer to in my question.  What I am asking is whether the format strings for those presets are available.  I will edit my question to clarify that.